# How can I access Angular functions client side in the browser console?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, client-side

For debugging purposes I would like to access my Angular module functions client-side in the console.

Is there a way to access the Angular $scope inside the console of a browser?

Comment: You can install  Chrome extension `ng-inspector` for AngularJS.

Comment: Here's a good read on the subject:  http://blog.ionic.io/angularjs-console/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint, you can examinate the scope value in this execution moment

Also you can install the Batarang extension for Chrome, and you will get direct access to your $scope s in the console browser

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek

Answer (score 0):

Open developer tools window (F12) in chrome --> go to sources tab --> find the js file where your specific function is in --> click on the line number in front to set the breakpoint --> press refresh(F5) in browser, and your browser will stop at the breakpoint.

Then type in the console en you can check the variables/objects witch are in scope of the specific javascript function